# Oracle PLSQL convert custom table type data to a JSON_OBJECT_T type data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new to Oracle PLSQL and I'm finding difficulty in finding the solution to convert the custom table object type data to a JSON_OBJECT_T type data using plsql login, please help

```
DECLARE
    input_data          XX_INPUT_TYPE;
    input_json          JSON_OBJECT_T;
    out_status          VARCHAR2(200) := 'SUCCESS';
    out_description     VARCHAR2(200) := 'Successful';
BEGIN
    
    input_data := XX_INPUT_TYPE();
    input_data.EXTEND;
    input_data(input_data.COUNT) := XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(124, 'Abc', 1000);
    input_data.EXTEND;
    input_data(input_data.COUNT) := XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(125, 'xyz', 100);
    
    -- i want to convert this custom type data to json something like below, but unable to do
    -- {"items" : [{"empid":124, "name":"Abc","salary":1000},{"empid":125, "name":"xyz","salary":100}] }
    
    input_json := input_data;
   
END;
```

my custom type specification as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE XX_OUTPUT_OBJ 
AS
OBJECT(
    EMP_ID      NUMBER,
    NAME        VARCHAR2(50),
    SALARY      NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE XX_INPUT_TYPE
IS TABLE OF XX_OUTPUT_OBJ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  input_data      XX_INPUT_TYPE;
  output_data     CLOB;
  out_status      VARCHAR2(200) := 'SUCCESS';
  out_description VARCHAR2(200) := 'Successful';
BEGIN
  input_data := XX_INPUT_TYPE(
                  XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(124, 'Abc', 1000),
                  XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(125, 'xyz', 100)
                );

  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'empid'  VALUE emp_id,
             KEY 'name'   VALUE name,
             KEY 'salary' VALUE salary
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
  INTO   output_data
  FROM   TABLE(input_data);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(output_data);
END;
/
```

or:

```sql
DECLARE
  input_data      XX_INPUT_TYPE;
  output_data     JSON_ARRAY_T := JSON_ARRAY_T();
  v_object        JSON_OBJECT_T;
  out_status      VARCHAR2(200) := 'SUCCESS';
  out_description VARCHAR2(200) := 'Successful';
BEGIN
  input_data := XX_INPUT_TYPE(
                  XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(124, 'Abc', 1000),
                  XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(125, 'xyz', 100)
                );

  FOR i IN 1 .. input_data.COUNT LOOP
    v_object := JSON_OBJECT_T();
    v_object.PUT('empid', input_data(i).EMP_ID);
    v_object.PUT('name', input_data(i).NAME);
    v_object.PUT('salary', input_data(i).SALARY);
    output_data.append(v_object);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(output_data.stringify());
END;
/
```

Which both output:

> ```json
> [{"empid":124,"name":"Abc","salary":1000},{"empid":125,"name":"xyz","salary":100}]
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9pzj3YHd)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `APPEND` function of JSON_ARRAY_T.
I wrote a simple example that prints DBMS output.

```
DECLARE
    input_data          XX_INPUT_TYPE;
    input_json          JSON_OBJECT_T;
    output_json_array   JSON_ARRAY_T;
BEGIN
    
    input_data := XX_INPUT_TYPE();
    input_data.EXTEND;
    input_data(input_data.COUNT) := XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(124, 'Abc', 1000);
    input_data.EXTEND;
    input_data(input_data.COUNT) := XX_OUTPUT_OBJ(125, 'xyz', 100);
    
    output_json_array := JSON_ARRAY_T();

    FOR i IN 1..input_data.COUNT LOOP
        output_json_array.APPEND
        (
         JSON_OBJECT 
         (
           'EMP_ID' VALUE input_data(i).EMP_ID
           ,'NAME' VALUE input_data(i).NAME
           ,'SALARY' VALUE input_data(i).SALARY
         )
        );
    END LOOP;

   FOR indx IN 0 .. output_json_array.get_size - 1
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (output_json_array.get_string (indx));
   END LOOP;
END;
```